# Кодировка кириллицы в консоле при использовании os.popen

Tags: python, кодировка

Вместо кириллицы выводит какие-то символы, что-то вроде этого. Как исправить?

```
import os
print(os.popen('dir').read())
# ‹®Є «мл© ¤аҐб Є
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема кодировки. Полагаю, что поможет один из следующих вариантов. Возьмите один.

```
import os

# Вариант 1
# после этого остальные варианты некорректны, перезапуск консоли понадобится
print(os.popen('chcp 1251').read()) 
print(os.popen('dir').read())

# Вариант 2
print(os.popen('dir').read().encode('cp1251').decode('cp866'))

# Вариант 3
import _locale
_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['ru', 'cp866'])
print(os.popen('dir').read())
```